# Splitting an Excel Sheet into multiple sheets using UI path

Tags: uipath

I would like to know how I can split an excel document into multiple excel documents with the records split equally.
For example If I have an excel of 200 records I have to split it through UIpath and give 2 Excel documents of 100 records each as Output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the Excel file to a datatable.
2. `for each row` the datatable and put the row value to 1. new datatable
3. check if your row number ( counter ) is `>` than datatable.rows.count/2. If yes, put the res on 2. new datatable.
4. Save both new datatable in 2 difference Excels files.